# How to apply image to inside of stroke (fill area)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, stroke, image-editing

I would like to know, how can I apply that stickerbomb image to fill the inside of a stroke, but not the stroke.

I mean I was trying to apply it in many ways but always it ended up with image on stroke and not inside of it.

[image: stickerbomb]

[image: stroke]

The stroke has been drawn in Illustrator if it matters.

I would like to manipulate the image inside of stroke as well.

I would like the image to appear like this:

[image: how I would like to have it]

Answer (score 1):

If the stroke is created in Illustrator and you intend to take this to Photoshop.....

Copy the stroke in AI.. Paste into PS, when asked paste as a **Shape Layer** (could also use Path).

You'll have a solid shape for the path. Then you can Command/Ctrl-Click the shape layer thumbnail to load it as a selection and apply a mask to your other "sticker" layer. Or use a clipping mask in Photoshop.

In this instance you really *don't* want a smart object when pasting. Having the path is more useful.